# Как построить график функции f(x,y) = 0?

Tags: математика, алгоритм

У меня есть функция f(x,y) = 0, программа должна построить её график. Функцию задает пользователь. Пример функции:

```
f(x,y) = x*y + sin(x+y)/ln(x)
```

Comment: в общем случае такие функции не разрешаются относительно х или у, поэтому тут надо посмотреть численные методы решения трансцендентных уравнений. если это учебная задача, то скорее всего вам соответствующие методы сообщали. если нет, то можно наверное попробовать рассмотредь метод
http://math.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/newtonsystemmod.html (Fixed Point Iteration in n-Dimensions). Надеюсь, здесь есть хорошие "численники", которые что-то поточнее подскажут, но вот как вариант..

Comment: знаю что они не разрешимы, но куда деваться?
спасибо за ссылку

Comment: пожалуйста, когда найдете соответствующий метод, отпишитесь - тоже вопрос давно волнует, но все как-то руки не доходили

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю [алгоритм](http://www.batesville.k12.in.us/physics/CalcNet/grapher/how_it_works.htm) с [одного сайтика](http://www.batesville.k12.in.us/physics/CalcNet/grapher/if_grapher.htm). Забавный график рисуется на вашу функцию.

Update:

Предложенный алгоритм корректный, но слишком медленный. Предлагаю ознакомиться с:

- [Marching_squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares)
- [Прога покруче](http://www.peda.com/grafeq/)

Update:

А теперь контрольный апдэйт! [Здесь](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/people/mooncake/papers/SIGGRAPH2001_Tupper.pdf) описан надёжный алгоритм того самого Jeff Tupper

Answer (score 1):

если просто нужно посчитать то: [вот](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x*y%2Bsin%28x%2By%29%2Fln%28x%29%2C+x%3D-10..10%2C+y%3D-10..10)